# how to browse field records of other model in odoo | openerp

Tags: python, odoo

In odoo new api,

I have model name :

```
_name = "service.rate.provider"
```

and its field:

```
base_currency_id = fields.Many2one('res.currency', string="Base currency")
```

base_currency_id records are coming from **res.currency** model.

If i am doing '**print self.base_currency_id**' it gives **res.currency(1,2,)**

but if i want to browse it for service.rate.provider model like: **service.rate.provider(1,2,)**

then how can i do?
Thanks in advance

Comment: you can  may be use .search() or .browse()

Answer (score 2):

Here `service.rate.provider` is your model, therefore in the class wherever you find `self` that is the recordset of this same model.

There are certain factors you need to keep in mind, which are as follows:

If you are using `self` in an **onchange** method and if that record is not saved than it will not be a recordset (browse) record, but using `self` will give every possible value of "form".

If you are using `self` in a *button click*, in that case it gives you a recordset (browse records) i.e  `service.rate.provider (1,2)` on which you can do the processing. Here you can use the decorator like `@api.one`.

If you are using `self` in a *fields.function*, it behaves the same as a button click providing you the recordset.

Also using this `self` you can call the **orm** methods like `search` or `browse` or `unlink` or `copy`.